# Python re sub replace word duplication

Tags: python, regex

```
re.sub(r'[\[\d\]]', 'foo', 'web scraping [2]')
```

I want to replace `[any number]` with `foo`. But the output is coming strange.

It prints `web scraping foofoofoo`

Why is it happening ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'\[\d\]', 'foo', 'web scraping [2]')` you have unnecessary outer  `[...]` that makes it a character class

Comment: Use `\[\d+\]` instead. You're matching any character in the list `[\[\d\]]`, which means match either `[`, `\d`, or `]` and replace each instance with `foo`

Comment: @ctwheels what is this `+` for ?

Comment: @RaheelKhan in case your number is greater than 9 such as `[10]`

Comment: I would suggest trying out your pattern at https://regex101.com/ if you are confused about what certain special characters do. There's an explanation box at the top right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra pair of square brackets. They are creating a character class where you don't want one.

Here is how to fix the regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[\d\]', 'foo', 'web scraping [2]')
'web scraping foo'
```

Note that this only accepts a single digit. If you want to accept multi-digit numbers, replace `\d` with `\d+`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace all numbers between brackets, you could use this way

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', 'foo', 'web scraping [2] [34] [567]')
'web scraping foo foo foo'
```